# Probability of distance between two points in an interval

Tags: combinatorics, graphing-functions

On interval [-2,4] we choose random numbers x and y. 
a)What is the probability, that distance between x and y is greater then distance between y and number 4.

I did this: $$|y-x|>|4-y|$$$$\frac{x+4}{2}<y$$
I draw a line and 'paint' the surface above the line, in range [-2,4] for both x and y in the coordinate system. The areas's surface is 9, surface of the whole area between [-2,4] for both x and y is 36. So, the probability is:
$$\frac{9}{36} = \frac{1}{4}$$ which is a correct answer. 
My question is: If I switch the above starting formula to $$|y-x|>|y-4|$$
I will get $$\frac{x+4}{2}>y$$
and the end result will be area under the graph. That would give me a wrong answer of $$\frac{3}{4}$$
How to approach this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether you use $|4-y|$ or $|y-4|$ you should get the same $x+4 < 2y$, so you did something wrong in between.

\begin{align}
|y-x| &> |y-4|\\
|y-x| &> 4-y & \text{you know $y \le 4$}\\
x > y + (4-y) & \text{ or } x < y - (4-y)\\
x &< 2y - 4 & \text{the first case is impossible}
\end{align}